# drop_duplicates after unionByName

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to stack two dataframes (with `unionByName()`) and, then, dropping duplicate entries (with `drop_duplicates()`).
Can I trust that `unionByName()` will preserve the order of the rows, i.e., that `df1.unionByName(df2)` will always produce a dataframe whose  first N rows are `df1`'s? Because, if so, when applying `drop_duplicates()`, `df1`'s row would always be preserved, which is the behaviour I want.

Comment: why does it matter which df row will be preserved? rows are exactly equal if they are dropped.

Comment: I would do drop_duplicates with subset, because the rows are not exactly equal. Basically, if an id-col is equal in both df1 and df2, I want the df1 row to have priority

Comment: Why don't you create the same PK in both dfs, filter the second df for the records not in df1 and then you union both (and drop the PK column)?

Comment: @LuizViola  that is possible but expensive, as it requires a left_anti join

Answer (score 1):

`UnionByName` will not guarantee that you will have your records ranked first from `df1` and then from `df2`. These are distributed and parallel tasks so you definitely can't build on that.

The solution might be to add a technical `priority` column to each DataFrame, then unionByName() and use the `row_number()` analytical function to sort by `priority`  within that `ID` and then select the one with the `higher priority`  (in below case 1 means higher than 2).

Take a look at the Scala code below:

```
val df1WithPriority = df1.withColumn("priority", lit(1))
val df2WithPriority = df2.withColumn("priority", lit(2))

df1WithPriority
 .unionByName(df2WithPriority)
    .withColumn(
      "row_num",
      row_number()
        .over(Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy(col("priority").asc)
    )
    .where(col("row_num") === lit(1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I see what you mean. Is this solution expected to be more efficient than the one @LuizViola mentioned in the comments of the question post? (excluding the common rows in df2 with a left_anti join and then applying the unionByName)

Comment: I think the @LuizViola idea will be more efficient :)  Try both and let us know what is the performance , ok?

Comment: It is very hard to assess performance, since I am running Pyspark inside Dagster's ops, but I will measure ops' execution time